# Extension of a smooth map from the boundary of a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $f: \partial M \to S^n$ is a smooth map, is it always possible to extend it to a map on $M$?

If $dim M > n$ it is not always possible for sure. Just consider $\overline{B}^m$. What about $dim M \leq n$? The usual partition of unity argument  does not work because one cannot guarantee that the extension stays in $S^n$.

Comment: Do you mean "what about $\dim M\leq n$"?

Comment: Because if you do, then the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Oh yes! I edited the question. Can you explain why? @AmitaiYuval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\dim M\leq n,$ then $\dim\partial M<n=\dim S^n,$ and this implies that $f$ is not surjective. So, you can think of $f$ as a map to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and as such, it can be extended from $\partial M$ to $M$.

Comment: Great! But just to be more specific: there is always a chart of $S^n$ covering $S^n \{some point}$, then your argument works. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @z.z Yes, this is what I'm saying.